# Hibernate HQL statement not returning correct results

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am having trouble with hibernate HQL query not returning a type of result based on the where statement below. I have 'actions' which have an attribute called 'event' this can be null for some actions that do not require an event. This is where the statement is having trouble, it won't return the actions with a null event when I an checking for the 'event.sections'. If I remove those checking statements `entity.event.section = 'xxx' or ...` then it starts to work. The row that it should be returning matches `entity.owner = 'xxx'` and `entity.assignee = 'xxx'`, meaning we have a successful match, stop checking. The strange thing to me is that HQL doesn't seem to be picking up that `entity.event is not null` so don't check for the sections too.

Hope this is clear enough for some help. Most appreciated!

```
(
   (
      (entity.status = '1') 
      and 
      (entity.owner = 'xxx' or entity.assignee = 'xxx' or (
          entity.event is not null and (
              entity.event.section = 'xxx1' or 
              entity.event.section = 'xxx2' or 
              entity.event.section = 'xxx3' or 
              entity.event.section = 'xxx4')
          )
      )
   )
   and entity.security = '1'
)
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a `or entity.event is null`?

Comment: Where do I need this?

Comment: after `or entity.assignee = 'xxx'` for example